# $0-$4 not recording last selected DOM elements in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, console.log

I've read on the Chrome command line API that I can use `$0-4` within the terminal to get the most recently selected DOM objects. However, I cannot get it to work as I expect.

```
$("#ev");
[<button type=​"button" id=​"ev">​Event attached to this button​</button>​]
console.log($0) //<body></body>
```

It looks like an array is returned at line 2, even though I was under the impression that `$` is an alias of `document.querySelector(...)`. So I've also tried `$("#ev")[0]` but had no better luck. How is this being incorrectly used?

Comment: As I understand it $0 is the element most recently selected in the dev tools (in the elements view), not most recent selected via a query.

Comment: @ray Yep, this is all taking place in the dev tools console.

Comment: I'm talking about selecting an element in the elements view, not "selecting" via a query like $("#ev");

Comment: You have to click on something in the `Elements` panel to record it.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#0-4

Comment: right click on the element, choose "Inspect Element", then click console and run `$0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to click on the element in the `Elements` panel to save it in `$0`. From [Using the Console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#accessing-recently-selected-elements-and-objects):

> **Accessing recently selected elements and objects**
>   The console stores the last five element and object selections. As you select an element in the Elements panel or an object in the Profiles panel, that pushes onto the history stack. `$x` provides access to the history stack. Remember computers begin counting from 0; this means the latest item is `$0` and the oldest item is `$4`.